# What is exactly Makefile.bak and what is its role?

Tags: git, makefile, patch

I have googled this question but cannot find a definition.

What is the `Makefile.bak` file and what is its role?

I have gathered that it is generated. According to [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2171) it is just a backup of the old Makefile done by a shell script. when is this generated? During building? I would appreciate more information

**General Background of the question (optional)**

Since it is generated, I reckon that it should not be included into the files managed by git, but unfortunately a `Makefile.bak` is being included in the repo I am working with. I got a patch to apply to the repo and it basically contains a change of this file. I am wondering if I can just ignore this patch since `Makefile.bak` is going to be generated anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see one for instance in [`Chronic-Dev/openssl`](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/openssl): that [`Makefile.bak`](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/openssl/blob/master/Makefile.bak) is identical to [`Makefile`](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/openssl/blob/master/Makefile), and is likely generated by a text editor backup process.

I would delete it and add it to the `.gitignore`:

```sh
git rm Makefile.bak
echo Makefile.bak>>.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Delete and ignore Makefile.bak"
git push
```

This differs from a:

- `Makefile.shared`: Helper makefile to link shared libraries in a portable way, simpler than `libtool`, and hopefully not too error-prone.
- `Makefile.static`: To compile statistically on your machine
- `Makefile.org`: source Makefile used by [`Configure`](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/openssl/blob/master/Configure) to generate the actual Makefile.